# MySql - LEFT JOIN on preference but have no duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates, left-join

So I have to join a table onto a value from another table however it should only return 1 value from the joined table.
The relationships of these tables are very vague - as is the nature of the data I am dealing with. The name in the ''Cookies'' table could be either one of `CookieAttr1`, `CookieAttr2` or `CookieAttr3`.

```
Cookies
|-----------------------------|
| CookieName  | CookieValue   |
|-------------+---------------|
| Choc-Chip   | 1200          |
| Dough       | 500           |
|-----------------------------|

CookieColor
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| Id  | CookieAttr1   | CookieAttr2   | CookieAttr3   | Color     |
|-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------|
| 1   |               | Choc-Chip     | Dough         | Red       |
| 2   |               | Choc-Chip     | Crumbs        | Orange    |
| 3   |               | Sultanas      | Dough         | Red       |
| 4   |               | Choc-Chip     | Dough         | Blue      |
| 5   | Dough         |               | Rounded       | Purple    |
| 6   | Dough         | Big           | Rounded       | Green     |
| 7   | Rounded       |               | Rounded       | Pink      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So far the table is joined on preference - where if `CookieAttr1` is null it will then join on `CookieAttr2` and then `CookieAttr3` (which will always have a value)

```
SELECT 
    CookieName,
    CookieValue,
    Color
FROM Cookies
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        Color,
        CookieAttr1,
        CookieAttr2,
        CookieAttr3
    FROM CookieColor
    GROUP BY CookieAttr3
) CookieColor
    ON COALESCE(CookieAttr1, CookieAttr2, CookieAttr3) = CookieName
```

The problem occurs that the table can return duplicates as grouping by `CookieAttr3` might have multple same `CookieAttr2` values on which it is joining on.

```
CookieColor (GROUPED BY `CookieAttr3`)
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| Id  | CookieAttr1   | CookieAttr2   | CookieAttr3   | Color     |
|-----+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------|
| 1   |               | Choc-Chip     | Dough         | Red       |
| 2   |               | Choc-Chip     | Crumbs        | Orange    |
| 5   | Dough         |               | Rounded       | Purple    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|

==========> result of query
|-----------------------------------------|
| CookieName  | CookieValue   | Color     |
|-------------+---------------+-----------|
| Choc-Chip   | 1200          | Red       |
| Choc-Chip   | 1200          | Orange    |
| Dough       | 500           | Purple    |
|-----------------------------------------|

==========> Preferred Result
|-----------------------------------------|
| CookieName  | CookieValue   | Color     |
|-------------+---------------+-----------|
| Choc-Chip   | 1200          | Red       |
| Dough       | 500           | Purple    |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

How can I only get one value for 'Choc-Chip'?

Comment: Which of the two `Choc-Chip` records would you like to retain and what is the logic behind that?

Comment: Isnt clear if that is the current result or your expected result. We need both.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen Either one of the choc-chip records. The color isn't that important as long as it is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a `COALESCE` in one subquery, but your group by isnt clear

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f23b0/4)**

```
SELECT CookieAttr, Color, CookieValue
FROM 
    (
      SELECT `Id`, 
              COALESCE(CookieAttr1, CookieAttr2, CookieAttr3) CookieAttr,        
              `Color`
      FROM CookieColor        
    ) C
JOIN  Cookies 
  ON C.CookieAttr = Cookies.CookieName
```

**OUTPUT**

But dont know what `group by` you want from this.

```
| CookieAttr |  Color | CookieValue |
|------------|--------|-------------|
|  Choc-Chip | Orange |        1200 |
|  Choc-Chip |   Blue |        1200 |
|  Choc-Chip |    Red |        1200 |
|      Dough | Purple |         500 |
|      Dough |  Green |         500 |
```

If you add

```
GROUP BY CookieAttr;
```

But color will be random.

```
| CookieAttr |  Color | CookieValue |
|------------|--------|-------------|
|  Choc-Chip | Orange |        1200 |
|      Dough | Purple |         500 |
```

Comment: Of course the logic was the wrong way! Needed to resolve the name first and then group by on the result. Your answer was helpful for my giant brain fart.